# A question on matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices

Let say I have set of real valued square matrices $\left(A_0, A_1, A_2, ..., A_n \right)$. All these matrices have constraint such that all `row-sum` of individual matrices equal to 1.

My question the `row-sum` of a matrix which is computed by multiplication of any subset of above set of matrices will remain to be 1? If yes, is there any matrix rule that govern this?

Comment: Use induction on $n$.

Comment: Denote by $\mathbf 1$ the column vector of ones. That all row sums of a matrix $A$ are equal to $1$ means precisely that $A\mathbf 1=\mathbf1$. Now, if $A\mathbf 1=\mathbf1$ and $B\mathbf 1=\mathbf1$, then $AB\mathbf 1=A(B\mathbf1)=A\mathbf1=\mathbf1$ and hence all row sums of $AB$ are equal to $1$. This argument generalises to a product of $n$ matrices.

Comment: @user1551 such an elegant proof. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrices you are referring to are *row-stochastic*. You can prove that the sum of each row will remain equal to one in many different ways. I will show it based on convex optimization arguments. Notice that you just need to show that the product of two of such matrices is one, since if it holds for 2 matrices, it also holds for $n$ matrices.

Consider then $A=X_1$ and $X_2$. Pick one row of $A$, let's name it $\alpha$. Then:

$$ \alpha^\top X= \alpha_1 x_1^\top + \ldots + \alpha_n x_n^\top$$

where $x_i^\top$ represents the $i$th row of matrix $X$.  Since $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i =1 $  what you are actually doing is a *convex combination* of vectors $x_i^\top$ which have sum-entries equal to one. As a result, the vector $\alpha^\top X$ has also a row-sum equal to one.

This is easy to show for instance if the number of row vectors in $X$ is $n=2$, because you would have:

$$\alpha_1 x_1^\top + (1-\alpha_1) x_2^\top$$ and if you sum the entries of this vector you obtain (assume each $x_n$ has $m$ entries):
$$\sum_{l=1}^m \alpha_1 x_1(m) + (1-\alpha_1) x_2(m)=  \alpha_1 \sum_{l=1}^m x_1(m) + (1-\alpha_1) \sum_{l=1}^mx_2(m)= \alpha+ 1 - \alpha=1$$